# Auto generate serial number number by input value and bind into GridView in Asp.net &C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, serialization, data-binding

May i know how to auto generate serial number by input value and bind into Gridview in asp.net & C# ?

For the example key in serial number  abcd001 in texbox1 , and  input value texbox2 is 10, then click add button it will auto generate serial number from abcd001, abcd002 abcd003 till abcd010 in bind gridview.

shall i adding a new column to datatable then generate value to each column by input value, and then bind in gridview ?

kindly advise. thank you

Comment: Post the code you have so far,  and the specific problems/Errors you are having - we're not going to write all that code for you

Answer (score 0):

Take it step by step, to help you, you can use this class I made to randomly generate new strings.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class RNGStringProvider
{
    private static readonly char[] Characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToArray();

    public string GetString(int length)
    {
        string chars = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            var bits = new Byte[1];

            do { rng.GetNonZeroBytes(bits); } while (bits[0] > 248);

            chars += Characters[bits[0] % 62];
        }
        return chars;
    }
}

// Type in the number of characters you wish to generate, this example creates 20.
var randomString = new RNGStringProvider().GetString(20);
```

Now that you have the code to do that, you can work on figuring out how to add this to the database.